# XCode Editor, Debugger, Build results all in one IDE

Tags: xcode, ide

I remember seeing it from the release notes of an earlier XCode version saying that it allows the three all in one IDE since then, instead of having to switch back and forth between the different windows when working on build, debug and editing. But with the latest XCode install, I still have to do that in separate windows. Is there a special setting to merge them all together under one IDE/window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in XCode preferences, called "All in one" layout. Check this:

http://img.skitch.com/20101121-xsxhc34ywurcf14yuhm6hna5qi.png

Note that in order for that to be changed - all projects must be closed.

Comment: Cool, that's what I wanted. Thanks a lot!